# modal close button

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a div which is in a class="modal", and I written a function in jQuery that closes this div when i press "esc" :

```
$(document).keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
        if ($('.modal:visible > .icon32').length) $('.modal:visible > .icon32')[0].click();
    }
});
```

everything works perfect in firefox, but in chrome does not, what could cause this problem?

Comment: Tip: Try debugging some more on your own. What isn't working?  The keypress, the keyCode, the click function?   Add a breakpoint and step through or add console.log lines to see where the program breaks from the expected route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have observed keypress have issues with IE as well. use **keydown** event instead.The keydown event happens when the key is pushed down. Immediately after that keypress event occurs. When you release key keyup event happens.

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
        if ($('.modal:visible > .icon32').length) $('.modal:visible > .icon32')[0].click();
    }
});
```

Comment: That's a correct solution. Chrome has issues processing `keypress` for some reason...